# Cmake3.13.0の相対パスコンパイルについて

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

初投稿になります。プログラム歴は2年の山口と申します。
Cmake3.13.0の相対パスコンパイルができない為、質問させていただきます。
http://kkkon.sakura.ne.jp/wp3/category/cmake/
上記のサイトを参考にさせていただき、
cmake.exe -DCMAKE_USE_RELATIVE_PATHS=ON -G "Visual Studio 15　2017　Win64"
とコンパイルしようとしたのですが、失敗してしまい、調べてみると
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_USE_RELATIVE_PATHS.html
上記URLの様に現在CMAKE_USE_RELATIVE_PATHSはなくなってしまっているようです。
そこでどなたか代案、又は、解答を理解している方がいらっしゃいましたら、
是非ともご教示頂きたいです。
どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 相対パスが必要とされる理由はなんでしょうか？

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。また、回答が遅くなり申し訳ありません。相対パスを使いたい理由としては、cmakeによりコンパイルした作成物を、他環境でも使用したい為です。

Comment: 「作成物」が何を指していて、絶対パスだと何が問題になるのかわかりませんでした。もう少し具体的な問題点を質問文に記載してくれますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

相対パスの必要性について返答がいただけず、またコンパイル失敗の詳細についても何も触れられていないため、期待する回答ではないかもしれませんが、

[Visual Studio 2015からCMake対応](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/ide/cmake-tools-for-visual-cpp?view=vs-2017)しています。現在Visual Studio InstallerからCMake 3.12がインストールできますので、こちらを使われることをお勧めします。